# Controller file not loading in PHP MVC

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

[image]

I am  stuck in a place where don't know how can I solve this issue. Actually I am trying to call a controller function from navigation menu.

In controller folder I have 2 files: `home.php` and `aboutus.php`

And from my `header.php` file I want to call these files as follows:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php base_url() ?>Home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php base_url() ?>about">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on Home or About Menu it doesn't navigate the page to home or `aboutus` page

---

`home.php` file

[image]

Comment: Because both of them have the same base URL. you need to build every URL of them in the way that your server expects, may be `<?php echo base_url() . "/home"` and `<?php echo base_url() . "/about"`, don't forget to echo the url, or use the shorthand `<?=  base_url()>`

Comment: i have change my code but its sowing Object not found error

Comment: I was giving you just an example, I don't know your URLs .  try this `<?php echo base_url() . "/home.php" ?>` or `<?php echo "/home.php" ?>`

Comment: i tried both links but same result "Page Not found"

Comment: my header.php file is placed in view folder do you think it can be a problem

Comment: I don't know what does your `header.php` file do . What is the return string from `base_url()` function?

Comment: Here  is config file setting `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/travel/';

Comment: try to hard-code the URL and see if it works or not, I mean replace `<a href="<?php base_url() ?>Home">HOME</a>` with `<a href="localhost/travel/Home">HOME</a>` or  `<a href="localhost/travel/home">HOME</a>`

Comment: when i click on menu it shows ur "localhost/travel/home" which is correct but result is same "object not found"

Comment: when i type  localhost/travel its loads the home page successfully but when i call it from header.php file it display error "Object not found"

Comment: Are you sure the URL that you typed by hand , Is the same exact URL that is generated from `<?php base_url() ?>` ? check if there is a slash or uppercase's or something different?

Comment: when i type localhost/travel it shows the home page .But when i click on Home menu then it display error and the url shows in address bar localhost/travel/home

Comment: if you navigate to ` localhost/travel/about` what happens?

Comment: same error "Object Not Found"

Comment: my deafult controller set to home as shown $route['default_controller'] = "home";

Comment: and its opening the home page but after clicking on home menu it shows error

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how is your framework controllers are configured. Where is `$route['default_controller'] = "home"` located ?

Comment: i have attached complete structure of directory and home.php file in controller through picture

Comment: OK, you question now began to be more answerable , In which file this configuration is located `$route['default_controller'] = "home"` ?

Comment: in config/routes.php

Comment: I'm sure the key to your problem is in that router, try to investigate it to see how the front controller did manage to route the requests.

Comment: i have changed the default controller to about page like this $route['default_controller'] = "about" and its showing the aboutus us very well ,i don't understand why the page not opening from navigation menu

Comment: triggering the default controller means that your front controller can't decide what is the controller that should handle the request , so he triggers the default controller. if you posted the `routes.php` It *might* help figure out what is going on.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed something, Try to remove the `/travel` part from the URL, try navigate to `localhost/about` or `localhost/about.php`

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';   this my routes.php file

Comment: http://localhost/travel/localhost/home      now this address is showing in address bar when i trying to navigate it to localhost/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like .htaccess file not present in your root directory ,just copy and paste the .htaccess file from any other project and make changes in the code as described by **Girish** , I hope this will help to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You have not configured proper re-write rules for run codeignter controller path, codeigniter is running all controller from `index.php`

did you tried url's with `index.php` like

> localhost/travel/index.php/Home
>
> localhost/travel/index.php/about

if above url's are working then configure your rewrite rules, when you are using apache server, then you can use following `.htaccess` in project root directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteBase /travel/ # if project is sub-directory
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    Options +Indexes
</IfModule>
```

**OR**

you can also set `index.php` path prefix in `config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: both settings are ok

Comment: yes its showing the page but not showing the pictures

Comment: Ok then, your server rewrite rules are not enabled, please enable apache rewrite module then `.htacess` will work.
Although, please use `site_url()` function instead of `base_url()` inside view links, `site_url()` will give complete path, if you have added `index_page` in `config.php`

Comment: When you will enable rewrite module then `index.php` path prefix won't need, you can also eliminate from `config.php` like `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: how can i enable apache rewriteable module

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting try it

Comment: i have changed all the settings according to your given link but the same result